# how to pass a constexpr string literal to other function

Tags: c++, constexpr

With the following two functions which is tend to get the length of a string literal at compile time. The first one won't compile, though the example is meaningless, but **I actually need to use the string length inside the `getlen` as a compile-time constant, how can I do that?**

```
// compile failed with "expression did not evaluate to a constant" in vs2019 std=latest
// failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime
// see usage of 's'
constexpr auto getlen(const char* s) {
    constexpr auto size = std::char_traits<char>::length(s);
    return size;
}

constexpr auto getlen2(const char* s){
    return std::char_traits<char>::length(s);
}

int main() {
    constexpr size = getlen2("suprise!") // size is 8
    return 0;
}
```

The second function shows that the returns of `getlen2` is indeed a constexpr, so must be the `s`. How to explain this?

Answer (score 2):

That's because a `constexpr` function can *also* be called at runtime, but the implementation of `getlen` makes only sense when called at compile-time:

```cpp
constexpr auto getlen(const char* s) {
    constexpr auto size = std::char_traits<char>::length(s);
    return size;
}
```

In the following context, it is clear `size` cannot be a `constexpr`:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    (void) getlen(argv[0]);
}
```

If you need your function to only be callable at compile-time, you might be interested in [`consteval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval).

Comment: So generally, this means I can not call other functions and use the return value which is not a constexpr later in other expressions ?

Comment: @zoujyjs not sure to understand you, mind to give an example?